# paypal is not checking to see if billing address matches credit card

Tags: php, paypal

So i am using the php api for paypal dodirectpayment, and this morning we noticed that if you have everything correct on the credit card, and had a valid address, but if the address does not match the billing address of the credit card the transaction will still go through. How do i fix this?

Comment: You want a PayPal transaction to fail if the address of the credit card payer doesn't match the address they provide to you? Sounds like that would block half of the online e-commerce sales. Thankfully, you would have to check this yourself and cancel the payment.

Comment: @Repox Thank you. My client seemed to be very worried about this. Could you provide an article about how not confirming address is not a security problem.

Comment: @oregano Well, not really - since this is not considered as a security issue, no one has written anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is an issue, if the address does not match it's obviously fraud! - We learnt this the hard way and lost around £5,000. It is common practice for transactions to be auto-declined by reputable merchants if the shipping address does not match the billing address.

My advice to your client is not to use PayPal as even if the card matches the billing/shipping address, the name the person can use does not need to match when using their Virtual Terminal and they do not fight charge backs from banks/credit card companies for you if they decide to charge back. You are then left not having a case in the Civil Courts because the name you took payment under was not the name the card was registered too, pathetic! I am now fighting PayPal for allowing this to happen which will go nowhere come to think of it but at least I can say I tried. We have had to fight several cases of fraud ourselves without help from the Police or PayPal.

My advice to your client, use a trusted merchant who uses something along the lines of Third-Man security to match the name and bank of the card as well as the billing/shipping address such as SagePay.

Answer (score 3):

- A name on the credit card is NEVER, EVER matched during an online transaction. It's rather a false impression one gets. With any payment provider (not just PayPal), only things checked for a "match" are Credit Card Number, Expiration Date, Issue Date (if applicable; European cards), 3-digit CVV/CVV2/CSC code.

The reason for this being, there are corporate cards, or gift cards
   with **no name** on them but that does not make them disqualified.

- An [Address Verification System (AVS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Verification_System) only verifies the numbers in an address. These numbers include the building/unit number and the ZIP / Post(al) code (which identifies city and state naturally).

So for example, if my Billing details REALLY are:

> John Smith
>  123 Main St
>  Los Angeles, California
>  95000

This would likely go through:

> Bryan Adams
>  123 Second St
>  Sacramento, California
>   95000

Wikipedia entry mentions:

> For example, if the address is 101 Main Street, Highland, CA 92346, in
>   the United States, AVS will check 101 and 92346. Cardholders may
>   receive false negatives, or partial declines for AVS from e-commerce
>   verification systems, which may require manual overrides, voice
>   authorization, or reprogramming of the AVS entries by the card issuing
>   bank.

A few ways to verify name/address:

- Use PayPal's [Address Verification API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/AddressVerify_API_Operation_NVP/) which matches an address against the confirmed address on a user's account.
- Mail in a letter: although slow and not as practical for your scenario, this one is used by [Google](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/157667?hl=en). Generate a Verification Code, print it on a letter and mail it to the address. The letter asking the user to log into their account and enter the verification code to verify their address.
- Least Reliable: Use Public records, including WhitePages.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You can use Whitepages Pro API for matching name/address/phone: http://pro.whitepages.com/developer/documentation/api-overview/ Disclaimer: I work for Whitepages.